# Matlab Loop not working

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

Can someone please tell me why r in downRight is always going up to 5 when I have said to record it's value as soon as downRight is given a value?

```
A = [5,16,18,4,9;
9,10,14,3,18;
2,7,9,11,21;
3,7,2,19,22;
4,9,10,13,8]

for r = 1:5
   normal = strfind(A(r,:), [7,9,11]);
    if isempty(normal) == 0;
        rowOfFirstNum = r;
        columnOfFirstNum = normal;
    end
end
for diags = -5:5
    downRight = strfind(diag(A,diags)', [10,9,19]);
    if isempty(downRight) == 0;
        rowOfFirstNum = downRight(1)+max(-diags,0);
        columnOfFirstNum = downRight(1)+max(diags,0);
    end
    downLeft = strfind(diag(rot90(A),diags)', [11,2,9]);
    if isempty(downLeft) == 0;
        rowOfFirstNum = downLeft(1)+max(-diags,0);
        columnOfFirstNum = downLeft(1)+max(diags,0);
    end
end
```

r should be 2 not 5 for cOfFirstNum in downRight, but it is always 5 i.e. the for loop has reached the end before it's value has been assigned to cOfFirstNum, why is this?

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are trying to run? This has many errors (e.g. the line `A = ...` is invalid, and the line starting `if is empty(downRight) == 0;` is also invalid).

Comment: Changed it, now it should work. I had to modify my original.

Comment: `Undefined function or variable
'normal'.`

Comment: Yeah sorry another mistake in the conversion, changed that now too. Never knew function "adaptation" could generate so many errors!

Comment: Ran it myself now and all the "stupid" errors are now gone lol!

Comment: `Undefined function or variable 'diagonal'.`

Comment: Sorry, me being an idiot again lol!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your error was to nest both loops, the inner loop checks for diagonals and has nothing to do with the outer loop which checks for rows:

```
A = [5,16,18,4,9;
    9,10,14,3,18;
    2,7,9,11,21;
    3,7,2,19,22;
    4,9,10,13,8]

for r = 1:5
    normal = strfind(A(r,:), [7,9,11]);
    if isempty(normal) == 0;
        rowOfFirstNum = r;
        columnOfFirstNum = normal;
    end
end
for diags = -5:5
    downRight = strfind(diag(A,diags)', [10,9,19]);
    if isempty(downRight) == 0;
        rowOfFirstNum = downRight(1)+max(-diags,0);
        columnOfFirstNum = downRight(1)+max(diags,0);
    end
end
```

Please double-check `rowOfFirstNum` and `columnOfFirstNum`, not shure if my solution is correct.

Comment: What can I use to fix it?

Comment: I think that works now. Would it work for downLeft, upRight and upLeft?

Comment: What is `upRight` and `upLeft`?

Comment: I have updated your code with downLeft. You get the gist though, numbers whose strings are in that direction.

Comment: Sorry got deleted for some reason, I have updated my original code now.

Comment: @user3071257: Please update your question, not my answer! The edit was rejected for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop doesn't depend on r:

```
for diags = -5:5
    downRight = strfind(diag(A,diags)', [10,9,19]);
    if isempty(downRight) == 0;
        rowOfFirstNum = downRight;
        columnOfFirstNum = r;
    end
end
```

So you are basically evaluating that statement five times:

```
downRight = strfind(diag(A,diags)', [10,9,19]);
```

and that statement is true for each "r-loop"

Comment: What can I use to fix it?